# “Other” permissions on files

Tags: permissions, filesystems, ls

To my understanding, the last three character of file permission printed by `ls` command is about other user's file permission.

If **the other user"s"** have separate file permissions to this file, what will the `ls` command show?

[image]

Comment: Are you using ACL permissions to give per user permissions?

Comment: Try it and see. You will need the `chmod` command to change the permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Unix traditionally distinguishes only three separate classes of users when it comes to permissions: (owning) user, (owning) group and world/others. That is, each file descriptor specifies one user ID and group ID for which specific permissions are used and then there is a third set of permissions which are applied to anybody not having that UID and not being in the appropriate group.

Since this is rather insufficient and constraining, modern filesystems support [access control lists (ACLs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) which allow specifying finer grained permissions in the form of a list of user and group IDs and their respective permissions. These are typically manipulated with the `getfacl` and `setfacl` utilities.

Answer (score 2):

File permissions are same for all users. Each file has single owner user name, owner group name. Each file has different rights for the owner user, owner group, and rest of the world. Every user see same output of the ls.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ls -l` command on terminal. It will display like this,

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 foo foo    4096 May  5 11:55 VirtualBox VMs
```

In the above the other user has read and execute permission on the directory but no write permission.

Comment: I edited the last line of my post to make it clear. :-)

Comment: there is no separate permissions for each other user.

Comment: ... unless you use ACLs.